# Блокируется ссылка iframe в письме

Tags: html

есть письмо в котором содержится iframe со ссылкой на gif с другого сайта. При загрузке письма в gmail эту ссылку блокирует CSP. Как решить проблему?

Comment: вставить картинку как картинку, а не как ифрейм

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Нужно именно iframe'мом

Comment: тогда никак. gmail блокирует потенциально опасный контент